# How to change image display duration in VLC lists for Android?

Tags: android, vlc

I have set this duration for lists on Windows over the setting 'demuxer', however the android version does not contain this option.

I'm actually creating the list dynamically over a php file in a server, so it looks like this:

#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:-1,
image1.png
#EXTINF:-1,
video1.m4v

So I wonder if there is an option in android to make images (not videos) display over a minute and if there is no such option, maybe I can add something to the list to make images display longer?

I have seen a tutorial for the list to use 1000 but it is a tag based language (html?), which seems not to be the case of my list. (link to tutorial: http://chris-reilly.org/blog/vlc-slideshow-duration/)

It is worth mentioning that in the Android version there is a small input for VLClib, but I was unable to find anything related to what I'm looking for.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is #EXTVLCOPT:image-duration=100 after each image file.  (change 100 for the number of seconds.

Found in https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=148945